# (ReactJS) Where to download the JSX file?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get started with ReactJS with JSX syntax. I've looked at the documentation, checked tutorials, etc. but CANNOT find any download that includes the required JSX file. In every tutorial however, there's a link to the same official download of React 15.1.0, and every site states that there should be a file called `JSXTransformer.js` in there. But there isn't.

Could anyone please provide me with a download link of the real thing? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSXTransformer is no longer a part of react:

> As many people have noticed already, React and React Native have both
>   switched their respective build systems to make use of Babel. This
>   replaced JSTransform, the source transformation tool that we wrote at
>   Facebook.

Source: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html

What you are going to want to do is use babel. There are many ways to implement this.

You can use gulp: https://jonsuh.com/blog/integrating-react-with-gulp/

You can use browserify: http://codeutopia.net/blog/2016/01/25/getting-started-with-npm-and-browserify-in-a-react-project/

Or (my personal choice) is to use webpack: http://jansoren.github.io/react-webpack-tutorial/

It's also worth mentioning that React also supplies a "Starter Kit" to get you started that you can find here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Ah, that explains, thanks. The starter kit seems to be the official React download though, as it's the only download that's on the official page.

Comment: I do have two questions about this though: What do gulp/browserify/ etc. do and what is the difference? Also do I need to install Babel or is that part of these things?

Comment: Gulp will run scripts and process your code for you. Browserify & Webpack can do what gulp does and more, like allowing you to use import/export syntax, etc. Babel is a code transformer/compiler; you can use different babel presets and such that your JSX and/or ES6/ES2015 (newer javascript syntax that isn't fully supported by default) get compiled into ES5 code that can be run on all major browsers.

https://babeljs.io/
https://webpack.github.io/

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

`JSXTransformer` is deprecated (https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html).

The state of the art is to, instead, process your project with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/browser/), using a builder tool such as [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io) (see http://survivejs.com/react/getting-started/setting-up-the-project/ and http://survivejs.com/webpack/introduction/), or [Brunch](http://brunch.io) (see http://github.com/brunch/with-react).